# How to parse this with gson

Tags: java, nested, gson

Here's the json data (I have no control over this)

```
{
"colors": {
    "668": {
        "name": "Pink Ice",
        "base_rgb": [
            128,
            26,
            26
        ],
        "cloth": {
            "brightness": 50,
            "contrast": 1.36719,
            "hue": 8,
            "saturation": 0.351563,
            "lightness": 1.36719,
            "rgb": [
                216,
                172,
                164
            ]
        },
        "leather": {
            "brightness": 47,
            "contrast": 1.71875,
            "hue": 8,
            "saturation": 0.234375,
            "lightness": 1.71875,
            "rgb": [
                207,
                170,
                163
            ]
        },
        "metal": {
            "brightness": 47,
            "contrast": 1.64063,
            "hue": 8,
            "saturation": 0.429688,
            "lightness": 1.48438,
            "rgb": [
                211,
                145,
                134
            ]
        }
    }
},
"657": {
    "name": "Pastel Pink",
    "base_rgb": [
        128,
        26,
        26
    ],
    "cloth": {
        "brightness": 52,
        "contrast": 1.40625,
        "hue": 8,
        "saturation": 0.585938,
        "lightness": 1.40625,
        "rgb": [
            247,
            170,
            157
        ]
    },
    "leather": {
        "brightness": 52,
        "contrast": 1.40625,
        "hue": 8,
        "saturation": 0.546875,
        "lightness": 1.40625,
        "rgb": [
            243,
            172,
            159
        ]
    },
    "metal": {
        "brightness": 47,
        "contrast": 1.5625,
        "hue": 8,
        "saturation": 0.546875,
        "lightness": 1.40625,
        "rgb": [
            220,
            141,
            126
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I can't for the life of me figure out how to construct the classes to store this.
The "668" (id num) is my stumbling block.

I know asking for help without showing what i've tried isn't good form, but nothing i've tried has even come close, and it would just take up lots of space to get nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class hierarchy would have the following skeleton

```
public class Holder {
    private Colors colors;
}

public class Colors {
    private Map<String, Item> map;
}

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int[] base_rgb;
    private Cloth cloth;
    ... // more
}

public class Cloth {
    private int brightness;
    private float contrast;
    private int hue;
    private float saturation;
    private float lightness;
    private int[] rgb;
}
```

You'll need classes for `Metal` and `Leather` and others.

The class `Holder` above would have been the one serialized to the JSON you've posted. If you don't want to name your fields like `base_rgb` (doesn't follow convention), you can use library specific annotations like `@JsonProperty` (not Gson) with a `name` attribute to give them a JSON name and name the field whatever you want.

Gson also provides a [`JsonSerializer`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) and `JsonDeserializer` to really customize serialization/deserialization.

Comment: I finally gave up on gson for it, after trying it with json-simple and it working on the first try.